# Is there a link to automatically open the first result in Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive, google-drive-search

I am looking for an equivalent to the Google Search "I'm feeling lucky" functionality. Whenever I know the first search result will be the file I am looking for, I would like to skip the actual search results page and directly open the first hit.

I'm feeling lucky: https://www.google.com/search?btnI=I%27m+Feeling+Lucky&q=stackexchange

Google Drive Search: 
https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/search?q=stackexchange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, Google's I'm feeling lucky works exclusively on their web search as it just forces the user to go the No.1 ranked hyperlink. The content in your Google Drive is not ranked in this manner thus an I'm feeling lucky button can't/won't work. The closest thing you have is something similar to Google Instant where a search term entered into your Google drive first returns results of files opened in the near past or opened most number of times.